# Trying to find where redirect on apache server is happening

Tags: apache2, redirect

I have a redirect on my website that immediately redirects to www.mydomain.com/wordpress/index.php however, I can not find the location of the redirect.

I removed the entire site so it is not coming from the home dir. 
I checked all .htaccess files.

Is there a way to increase logs to the point of showing me where the redirect is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

You probably figured out by now, but here a couple of tips:

1. First one, check that you don't have some `.htaccess` doing the redirection 
   (you already did that)
2. Make a `grep -R wordpress` on the /etc/apache2/ directory, to see if you find some redirection
3. Very important: Erase the cache of your browser! Or use a different one :)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite) is someone else who had a similar problem.

So, for versions before 2.4, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

to the apache.conf file. And for newer ones, just:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```